# How to remove a two-factor provider for a user in Identity Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, identity, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to implement multiple two-factor methods with Identity core/.net7.

Calling the function `UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user)` gives me a list of the methods the user enabled. These methods can be used later to verify their token during sign in.

But, how can I remove one method from the active list. For example, if a user no longer wants to use the `Authenticator` or `SMS` methods from their providers, what do I do to remove that method?

There is a method to reset the Authenticator called `UserManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user)` but that does not remove `Authenticator` from the valid two factor providers returned by `GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user)`.

How can I remove a two-factor provider for a user in Identity?

Comment: The only thing I could find in the documentation was [this example](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreHybridFlowWithApi/blob/main/IdentityStandaloneMfa/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Disable2fa.cshtml.cs), which essentially says you do something in the lines of this: ```await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, false);```

Comment: @PeterSchrøder yes that disables the two factor authentication. It does not remove a method.